# Is there a direct way to import a file sytem as an AWS EBS volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Say I use these two commands to create a file system "data.dd":

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./data.dd bs=1M count=5
mkfs.ext2 ./data.dd
```

It seems like it should be straightforward but despite many hours of trying different parameters and options I couldn't find a direct way to import a disk as an EBS volume using either

```
ec2-import-volume
aws ec2 import-snapshot
```

Anyone know if this it can be done?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to make a new (empty) EBS volume? Or are you trying to copy/move/import a disk from a non-EC2 computer into an EBS volume for use with EC2? Does the documentation help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/importing-your-volumes-into-amazon-ebs.html